# Compare DateTime with milliseconds in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am building a windows service that fetches data from an SQL Database and stores them in a .txt file every 5 minutes. What I am trying to do is every 5 minutes when my service checks the database, it should check the last datetime record on the txt file and find it in the database. If it finds the same datetime, it should fetch all the newer records after that datetime. I am trying to be as precise as possible and not miss a records, so I thought it would be a good idea to compare the milliseconds of each date. This is what I have so far, but I know that x.Datetime, which is of type DateTime, does not fetch the milliseconds along with the date. "lastDate" is the date I fetch from the txt file with milliseconds added to it.

```
dbData = db.Table.Where(x => x.Datetime < lastDate).ToList();
```

Also, the column on the database has milliseconds stored with the datetime.

Comment: "does not fetch the milliseconds", what exactly do you mean by this? Fetch how, and from where? If the two DateTime values that are being compared have millisecond values, they will for sure be part of the comparison.

Comment: try to look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-display-milliseconds-in-date-and-time-values)

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt")

Comment: I got my comment exactly where @Ben.S told you so :)

Comment: `dbData = db.Table.Where(x => x.Datetime < lastDate).ToList();` will get you all entries **before** (as in "older than") `lastDate`. Like "2020-06-01" < "2020-12-31"

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enought. What I was trying to say is that eventhough the x.Datetime, which is fetched from the db, has milliseconds in its column on the database (here's an example "2020-12-10 12:08:00.200"), when I check the value of x.Datetime on the program x.Datetime only holds 14/12/2020 13:56:47 without the milliseconds.

Comment: Are  you sure this isn't just formatting?

Comment: A Tick is 100ns.  There is a constant TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond .  So 5 minutes is 300 seconds.  So if you divide the Tick value by 300 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond you will get dates to be in 5 minute groups.

Comment: @jdweng But then you are prone to miss singular or have duplicate rows due to rounding. I am with Gert's suspicion, OP is simply not _seeing_ millis because of default formatting in the IDE. _And_ OP is using the wrong operator.

Comment: @Fildor : I depends on the requirements.  Normally you will sample quicker than the 5 minutes and then average the values.  But you always can have the case where the data changes right on the edge of the 5 minute period.  that is why you normally sample in the middle of the 5 minute range.   so to be more robust you can add a 2 1/2 minute offset.

Comment: Is it an option to include a unique incremental id in the query, and also write it in the text file, so that you can keep the file in sync with the database, without the risk of missing any records?

Comment: @jdweng. Yes, "normally". But that doesn't seem to be what OP is doing.

Comment: @Fildor : It is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

So the rows in your table have a property Datetime. You only want to fetch rows that you haven't fetched before and you don't want to miss any rows.

The problem is, that as soon as your query returns, new rows might already be added. So before you process the fetched data at millisecond X, new data might already be added

It would be better to remember the DateTime of the last added row:

```
private DateTime lastFetchedDate = ...
```

Call the following procedure every few minutes:

```
private void FetchAndProcessNewData()
{
     var dbData = db.Table.Where(row => row.Datetime > lastFetchedDate)
                .OrderByDescenting(row => row.DateTime)
                .ToList();
    if (dbData.Any())
    {
        ProcessFetchedData(dbData);
        lastFetchedDate = dbData[0].DateTime;
    }
    // else: no new rows; nothing to process, no new lastFetchedDate needed
}
```

It is a bit of a waste to order all rows. A small optimization would be to not order the list, but calculate the max DateTime. This way you do'll only have to enumerate the fetched data once

```
lastFetchedDate = dbData.Select(row => row.DateTime).Max();
```

There is no Max for DateTimes, but the extension method is fairly easy to create. If you are not familiar with Extension methods, see [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static DateTime Max(this IEnumerable<DateTime> source)
{
    // TODO: exception if source == null
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

    // initialize the first DateTime as the largest:
    if (enumerator.MoveNext()
    {
        var max = enumerator.Current;

        // enumerate the rest:
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (enumerator.Current > max)
                max = enumerator.Current;
        }
        return max;
     }
     // else: empty source. Decide what to do: exception? return DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

Usage:

```
var dbData = db.Table.Where(row => row.Datetime > lastFetchedDate).ToList();
if (dbData.Any())
{
    ProcessDbData(dbData);
    this.lastFetchedData = dbData.Select(row => row.DateTime).Max();
}
```